# How to schedule a notification based on user input using Flutter for Android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, notifications

My goal:

When a user clicks a button that says "5 minutes", it schedules a notification in 5 minutes. Then 5 minutes passes and the notification pops up. It should give the notification even if my app is closed/not active.

I have tried awesome notifications, local notifications, and FCM (but it doesn't support such a function it seems), and I have not found a suitable solution. For awesome notifications, I somewhat got it to work, but I guess it only works if my app is open? And it did not work for all emulators/devices? The point is to get a notification even if my app is closed and not working.  So how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about awesome notifications but if you want to get notifications to fire even when the app is closed here is my NotificationAPI I created to use in an app.

It uses "flutter_local_notifications" as well as a few other dependencies that you can possibly rip out if needed.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_timezone/flutter_timezone.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart';

class NotificationApi {
  static final _notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static final onNotifications = BehaviorSubject<String?>();

  static bool notificationPermission = true;

  static Future _notificationDetails() async {
    return const NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channelID',
        'channelName',
        channelDescription: 'channelDescription',
        //importance: Importance.unspecified,
      ),
      iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),
    );
  }

  static Future init({bool initScheduled = false}) async {
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    const ios = DarwinInitializationSettings();
    const settings = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: ios);

    //When app is closed
    final details = await _notifications.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    if (details != null && details.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
      onNotifications.add(details.notificationResponse?.payload);
    }

    await _notifications.initialize(settings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: ((payload) async {
      onNotifications.add(payload.payload);
    }));

    if (initScheduled) {
      initializeTimeZones();
      final timeZoneName = await FlutterTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
      setLocalLocation(getLocation(timeZoneName));
    }
  }

  //This is how to request and check permissions on ANDROID and IOS
  static Future<bool?> checkNotificationPermissions() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      _notifications
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.requestExactAlarmsPermission();
      await _notifications
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.requestNotificationsPermission();

      return await _notifications
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.areNotificationsEnabled();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return await _notifications
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.requestPermissions(
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
          );
    }
    return null;
  }

  static void showScheduledNotification({
    required int id, //This must be a unique ID I recommend a UUID package
    String? title, 
    String? body,
    String? payload,
    required DateTime scheduledDate, //When you want the notification to happen
  }) async =>
      _notifications.zonedSchedule(id, title, body,
          TZDateTime.from(scheduledDate, local), await _notificationDetails(),
          androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
          uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
              UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
          payload: payload);

  static void cancel(int id) => _notifications.cancel(id);
  static void cancelAll() => _notifications.cancelAll();
}
```

I put some comments in the most important parts but the code should be pretty simple to follow.

For more details specific to a chunk of code: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Dependencies:
https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart
https://pub.dev/packages?q=flutter_timezone
https://pub.dev/packages/timezone

NotificationAPI init gets called in an initState. Here is a basic initState to get started.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    await NotificationApi.init(initScheduled: true);
    listenNotifications();
    NotificationApi.checkNotificationPermissions().then((value) {
      NotificationApi.notificationPermission = value ?? true;
    });
  });
}
    
void listenNotifications() => NotificationApi.onNotifications;
```

Once the initState and init are setup, you know you have permissions, and have done all the setup.

**PLEASE REFER TO https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications ANDROID AND IOS BOTH NEED TO SETUP PROPERLY**

All you need to do is:

```
NotificationApi.showScheduledNotification(
  id: id,
  scheduledDate: scheduledDate,
  title: "TITLE",
  body: "TEXT",
);
```

This will schedule the notification and even if you close the app it will fire at that exact time. Again assuming you setup local notifications properly following the guide on Pub.dev